# Table Cell Overflow Depending on Table Row Width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a single-line meta data for news list, and I'd like the columns in the middle to to overflow: hidden with an ellipsis at the end if they are too long, while otherwise keeping all columns left-aligned except for the last column.

Maybe the following examples will explain this better:

```
Time  |  Categories  |  Tags  |                                                        Read More (right-aligned)

2015-05-06 21:02  |  Category  |  Tag  |                                               Read More <-- normal
2015-05-06 21:02  |  Category, Category, Category, Category, Category...  |  Pie  |    Read More <-- many categories
2015-05-06 21:02  |  Category  |  Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag...  |    Read More <-- many tags
2015-05-06 21:02  |  Category, Category, Category...  |  Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag...  |      Read More <-- many categories and tags
```

Is this possible? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Use a two-column table with all the "left-aligned colums" thrown together in the first column.

Comment: WRT the ellipsis, what conditions do you have for deciding which field to truncate? I see in your example that sometimes the second field is truncated, sometimes the third, but how would you choose? Based on the content of the third field being "Pie"?

Comment: @MrLister, if category and tag fields are both long, truncate them both, otherwise truncate the longer one. Pie has nothing to do with this and is thus a lie.